# How to call an element which I need in django massive?

Tags: python, html, django, web

I have such code

```
{% for x in list %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>{{ x.title }}</h3>
                    <span>{{ x.category }}</span>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I need a certain element from this massive in different divs.
For example

```
{% for x in list %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>{{ 3.title }}</h3>
                    <span>{{ 1.category }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3>{{ 4.title }}</h3>
                    <span>{{ 3.category }}</span>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I need such grid in one loop How can I do it?

http://blog.eney.solutions/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/12/737781.png[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwJOX.png)

Answer (score 0):

look at [Variables and lookups (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) .

I think you can try something like this:

```
{{ list[0].title }}
```